# Should we input Chinese characters in a table of summarizing vernacular names in a Scientific Paper? or only write in Pinyin

Tags: publications

I got a comment from a reviewer  who suggested that i should remove Chinese character in the table which shows different names of a plant from different countries. Actually i typed pinyin( Chinese character), namely Ding Cao(丁草). I saw several published papers do the same thing. But i have no academic proof or authentic documents so far. So please share or give some consultancies if someone encountered. Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you have the English name of that plant? If you do, did you use that English name?

Comment: Yes i did. The plant has a English name. we would like present a table of vernacular names from different countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion differs from the reviewer. I think that for maximum readability across countries, your solution is very good. Including the local names as well as a translation when appropriate makes your results accessible for more people, especially as you are dealing with international data. Some kinds of research will depend on having the "official" name expressed in the local way.

But, it may be that the reviewer is also concerned about the difficulty of typesetting your paper at that particular journal. They may be correct or not. It might be worth a note to the editor asking if including various non-Roman scripts in the paper will cause any difficulty. At this point in time they should not, but the editor will know for sure.

Comment: Publishers don't fund research, don't perform the research, don't write the articles, don't review the articles, often don't even manage the peer review process themselves, charge exorbitant fees, and then claim ownership and copyright over the ideas they publish (often not even on paper)… If I have to ask for permission to use my own work in my own thesis, the least they could do is typeset a Chinese character!

Comment: @Buffy. Thanks very much for your explanation. I have the same your thought, showing more clarification in the languages which may support readers to access more information in their own language in need.  It makes sense.